# minio ilm configuration suggestion needed

Tags: storage, restore, minio, ilm

Hello Im working with minio these days and found out there is a feature which configures the life cycle of the minio objects, which is called ilm. And I can set the storage class as the tier to transit the object data to it.

the official explanation is posted in the below url.

https://min.io/product/automated-data-tiering-lifecycle-management

So if I set the expiration day to 1 it expires the buckets prefix or if I set the transition options it send the data to the configured tier which is the storage class I was intending to send.

after the transition the data was actually transited to the new storage class but the meta data was in the original bucket so that I can use it as if it is in the original bucket.

But I realized that after I delete the life cycle ( ilm ) the file does not come back to the original bucket. But when I deleted the ilm I expected the data to be restored in the original bucket but it did not work that way.

I searched the official documentation of minio but could not find the best answer for my problem.

so the point is that

1. After deleting the ilm of the bucket the file does not come back to the original bucket
2. So is there a configuration for ilm to get back the datas to the original bucket?
3. is there an ilm configuration to get back the datas to the original bucket if I use the data recently?

Any suggestion will help me a lot : )

Answer (score 0):

Once the object is transitioned, it stays in the remote tier. There is no API to move the data back, there is a RestoreObject API, that can be issued https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_RestoreObject.html

The data does not automatically move back to hot tier.

The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.